# Explicit instantiation of a function template parameterized on a templated function

Tags: c++, templates

In c++ it is allowed to create a template on functions, both member and free

```
template <void (*F) ()> void function1 ();
template <void (MyClass::*M) ()> void function2 ();
```

and instantiate them explicitly

```
function1 <&fn> ();
function2 <&MyClass::doSomething> ();
```

my question is, if the template arguments themselves are instantiated from templates

```
template <typename R, typename C, R (C::*M) ()> void function3 ();
```

how do I instantiate `function3` explicitly (if even possible)?

Comment: Do you mean template template arguments? You need to instantiate the template arguments and pass an instantiated type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do:

```
function3<void, MyClass, &MyClass::doSomething>();
```

The syntax is just the same in this case as in the other cases.

Complete compilable example:

```
#include <iostream>
class MyClass {
public:
    void doSomething() {
        std::cout << "doSomething\n";
    }
};
void fn() {
    std::cout << "fn\n";
}
template <void (*F) ()> void function1 () {
    F();
}
template <void (MyClass::*M) ()> void function2 () {
    (MyClass().*M)();
}
template <typename R, typename C, R (C::*M) ()> void function3 () {
    (C().*M)();
}
int main() {
    function1<&fn>();
    function2<&MyClass::doSomething>();
    function3<void, MyClass, &MyClass::doSomething>();
}
```

Prints:

```
fn
doSomething
doSomething
```

Comment: Right, I can't believe I missed that. I was somehow under the impression that since `R` and `C` are already included in the type of `M` then I can omit them. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct MyClass
{
        int doSomething() { return 1; }
};

template <typename R, typename C, R (C::*M) ()>
R function3(C* c) 
{
        return ( (c->*M)() );
}

int main()
{
        typedef decltype(MyClass().doSomething()) R_type;
        MyClass cls;
        function3<R_type, MyClass, &MyClass::doSomething>(&cls); // instantiation
        return 0;
}
```